# Intent abrindo duas Activity na pilha

Tags: android

Eu tenho uma *Activity* que ao chamar outra *Activity* chama normalmente a outra tela, o problema que tenho que sair da outra tela duas vezes para voltar a primeira. Estou chamando *Activity* em um evento de um `EditText`, ao da enter no teclado:

```
campoBusca.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View arg0, int onKey, KeyEvent arg2) {
            // se pressionar enter
            if (onKey == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
                //chama a tela passando por parametro a url
                Intent telaSegmento = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SegmentoView.class);
                Bundle bundleParametro = new Bundle();

                URL = "www.xxx";
                bundleParametro.putString("id", URL);

                telaSegmento.putExtras(bundleParametro);
                startActivity(telaSegmento);

                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Atividade 2:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // carrega o layout onde contem o ListView
    setContentView(R.layout.empresa_lista);
    ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
    bar.hide();

    Intent dadosRecebidos = getIntent();
    if (dadosRecebidos != null) {
        Bundle parRecebidos = dadosRecebidos.getExtras();
        if (parRecebidos != null) {
            URL = parRecebidos.getString("id");
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    finish();
}
```

Ao invocar o método `onBackPressed()` , ele fecha a atividade, mas é como se estivesse outra, ai tenho que mandar sair de novo, ai ele volta para primeira *Activity*. Alguém me ajuda?

Comment: Tem certeza que o método onKey não está iniciando duas Activities? Além disso eu acho que não é preciso chamar o método finish no onBackPressed, ele já faz isso pra você. Faltou além disso chamar o `super.onBackPressed`, que ficaria no lugar do `finish`.

Comment: O metodo é esse que lhe mostrei, sim, tenho que sair duas vezes, para voltar para tela anterior, eu ja chamei essa activity de outro local, e so preciso pressionar 1 vez pra sair, mas do jeito q to chamando ai ta chamando duas.

Comment: Não há necessidade de sobrescrever o método `onBackPressed()` nesse caso. Pode remover esse método do código. A implementação padrão desse método já chama `finish()`.

Comment: @Wakim Acho que o problema é esse mesmo que você falou, o método `onKey()` deve estar sendo chamado duas vezes, uma quando a tecla Enter é pressionada e outra quando ela é solta. Por que não complementa seu comentário e o converte em resposta? É só chamar `if (onKey == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER && arg2.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você atualmente está sobrescrevendo um método que no seu caso não seria nem um pouco necessário sobrescrever, que seria o `onBackPressed()`, você deve remover este evento de seu código pois ele em suas internas já finaliza a atividade, da forma correta.

Após retirar este evento note que ao abrir sua atividade e depois clicar em voltar a sua atividade irá fechar normalmente.

## Adicional:

Para melhor entendimento seu, dependendo do que você deseja, pode chamar uma Activity de formas diferentes, como por exemplo, se você que apenas iniciar a Activity (que é o que você está atualmente fazendo):

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SegmentoView.class);              
startActivity(i);
```

Ou chamar uma atividade esperando por um resultado(quando você fechar a atividade irá cair no evento `onActivityResult` da atividade origem(a que chamou))

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SegmentoView.class);              
startActivityForResult(i, 1); //sendo 1 para request code
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        //
    }
}
```

E na atividade que você chamou:

```
setResult(RESULT_OK);
```

Ou até chamar uma atividade esperando por resultado, mas enviando parâmetros:

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SegmentoView.class);              
i.putExtra("PARAMETRO", 1 );
startActivityForResult(i, 1); //sendo 1 para result code esperado
```

Então no `onCreate()` da outra atividade você tem:

```
Bundle extras    = getIntent().getExtras();
SeuParametroInt  = extras.getInt("PARAMETRO");
```

**Essas explicações são apenas para intuito de entendimento de como funciona a iteração entre atividades android, espero ter ajudado**.

Comment: O problema não está sendo causado pela sobrescrita de `onBackPressed()`; a versão sobrescrita é desnecessária porém funciona como esperado. Veja os comentários da pergunta para a provável causa do problema.

Comment: Bom eu respondi desta forma pois tive um problema similar há um tempo atrás, estou esperando a manifestação do OP sobre

Comment: funcionou da forma que foi dita la em cima, era o evento Onkey q tava errado, sobre sobreescrever o metodo, obrigado pela dica. valeu